Query to get record latest status of a record if its null then i need to raise a alert else just take the latest value
I have two table  V1 and V2 both are joined on ID column and have left outer on V2 table i want to monitor the rate column if on a date its null will have to raise alarm but always check on the latest date even on older value are null no need to raise alarm.
V1 table
id code rate timestamp
1  A    10   08/12/2024 
1  A    NULL 08/12/2024
1  A    20   07/12/2024 

V2 table
id status
1  open
2  open

so if on 12 NULL came in the column need to find that record
select s.timestamp,s.rate from v1 s
left join v2 e on e.id = s.id
where  
s.rate is null
and 
e.status = 'OPEN'
group by s.timestamp,s.rate
order by s.timestamp desc


Use a subquery to get all the rows with the latest date. Then check whether there's a null rate in the results of that subquery.
You also need to put conditions on a LEFT JOINed table in the ON clause. If you put it in WHERE, it will filter out rows that have no match, making it effectively an INNER JOIN.
SELECT timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM v1 AS s
    LEFT JOIN v2 AS e ON e.id = s.id AND e.status = 'OPEN'
    WHERE s.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM v1)
) AS t1
WHERE t1.rate IS NULL

